# CSS div fade when hovering over another element which is child of a sibling

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a Wordpress website which uses the [Dune theme from Zigzagpress](http://demo.zigzagpress.com/dune/).

You can check the site [here](http://www.streetrunners.net).

What I want to do is, when hovering over an image, remove the grey layer that the `post_image_overlay` div has.

I've tried doing it by adding this custom css to the file provided in the theme to do so, `custom.css`, which gets loaded along with the theme's css:

```
.post_image_overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.post_image_overlay:hover {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .55s ease-in-out;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to make any difference. In fact, with the Chrome inspector and the custom.css file properly loaded, I can see my custom css rules in the `.post_image_overlay` (for example, if I change the opacity to `0.5`, the background is not as dark), but I can't see the `.post_image_overlay:hover` anywhere. I've even tried to add it directly in the Chrome inspector, but it gets greyed out:

[image]

I'd post a JSFiddle but I believe the problem lies beneath some other CSS in the page which is conflicting with my custom one, so I guess it's better to check it live.

**BONUS POINTS**: Ideally, I'd love to have the background fading out only when the user hovered over the entry title (`h2.entry-title`), not all the image, but I don't really know if that can be done.

Comment: did you try adding `!important`?

Comment: Chrome inspector grays out rules that are currently not in use. If you hover over the element, you should see the rules become activated. You can also force state on the element by right clicking on the element in the source view (next to the inspector rules) and clicking `:hover`.

Comment: Selecting `:hover` in the Chrome inspector does the trick, but hovering over the element itself doesn't. So I'm still thinking about some other CSS overruling it.

Comment: Looking at your site, custom.css is empty, and your `.post_image_overlay` doesn't have a hover style?

Comment: Jamie, I removed it because it was not working. I uploaded it again now.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because your `.entry-content-title` has a `z-index: 1002;` style, which means it's sitting over the top of your `.post_image_overlay` and therefore you're not hovering over it.

Comment: So is there any way to make the `.post_image_overlay` fade when I hover over the `.entry-content-title` element?

Comment: @Samer As it currently stands, without JavaScript, no. If you swapped them around though and put entry content title before it's previous sibling, you would be able to by doing .entry-content-title:hover + .sibling > .post_image_overlay